# Flask colorbox ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, colorbox

I am using Jquery colorbox and flask. When the user hits an icon the script submits a url to render the form inside the colorbox. When the user hits the save button the form is submitted and the colorbox closes. The problem is I just want the box to close, and not reload the screen, although that works fine there is no reason to redraw it. The thing I do not understand is how you return nothing, or do nothing in the view that causes the screen to reload. Here is the view code:

```
@listings.route('/notes/<string:find>',methods=['GET','POST'])
def notes( find = None ):
""" Ajax call to handle notes
"""
    find = Found.objects.get( pk = find )
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('note.html', find = find )

    if 'save' in request.form:
        find.notes = request.form['note']
        find.save()

    #return redirect( url_for('listings.landing', search=find.search.pk))
    return '',200
```

The redirect reloads the screen and the return '',200 cause a blank screen. How do I tell flask to do nothing on return?

Comment: flask isn't what is reloading your page.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not Flask ... the "issue" is the browser (and indirectly, the HTTP protocol).  If you return a `30X` level response the browser issues a new request for the redirect URL transparently ... and in the case of a `200` response the browser will display what it received to the end user (in most cases).  This is because a `redirect` says "the thing you are looking for is actually found at this other address" and a `200 OK` says "you found what you are looking for, and here it is".

You will want to return a [`204 No Content`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5) rather than a [`200 OK`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.1):

```
return '', 204
```

A `204` response says to the consuming entity, "nothing new here, I did what I needed to and I don't have anything to say to you about it".  In the browser, this results in the page from which the request was made staying on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it worked I just wanted to share what I did to finally get it work. I had to use this

```
    .on('click', '#colorbox .cancel, #colorbox .note', function(e) {
    if ( $(this).attr('class') == 'note' )
        $('.notes').submit();

    $.colorbox.close();
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

and the html looks like this

```
<form action="{{url_for('listings.notes', find=find.pk)}}" method='post', class='notes'>
    <textarea  rows="4" cols="45" name='note'>{{find.notes|safe}}</textarea>
    <div class="bottom">
        <a href='#' class="cancel">cancel</a>
        <input type='submit' name='save' value='save' class='note'/>
    </div>
</form>
```